# Is the Principled shader a combo of all shaders?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders

I heard that the new Principled shader is a combination of all the other shaders. Is it true? If yes, then can you please list all of the shaders/nodes that are obsolete now.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**No.** The **Principled BSDF** shader is a combination of several other shaders, but it is *not* a replacement for them. From the [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/shaders/principled.html):

> It is based on the Disney principled model also known as the “PBR” shader, making it compatible with other software such as Pixar’s Renderman® and Unreal Engine®. Image textures painted or baked from software like Substance Painter® may be directly linked to the corresponding parameters in this shader

None of the current nodes are obsolete or deprecated. There are, however, two main advantages to this shader:

First, as you pointed out, it is a combination of the other shaders, *using physically based formulae*. This means that we can plug is colors and values without having to worry whether or not what we are creating looks realistic. (This means that it has built-in Fresnel).

This second advantage is that it uses Disney's standardized shading model, making it so that results with Cycles should match up with results in **Renderman**, **Unreal** and **Substance Painter**. This can save a lot of time, especially for someone who switches between software.

It isn't a replacement for any nodes, though, since it might be **faster** or **simpler** to just use more basic nodes.

Of the 16 other shading nodes (not including **Add**, **Mix**, and **Principled**), these 5 can be replicated with **Principled BSDF**:

- Anisotropic BSDF
- Diffuse BSDF
- Glass BSDF (called Transmission)
- Glossy BSDF (called Specular)
- Subsurface Scattering<sup>1</sup>

**Principled BSDF** does *not* cover any Volumetric shaders, transparencies other than **Glass**, or more specialized effects like **Velvet**<sup>2</sup>, **Toon**, **Ambient Occlusion**, or **Hair**.

---

<sup>1</sup> While this does simulate Subsurface Scattering, it does not use the same algorithms as the Cycles **Subsurface Scattering** node, see [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/106255/26640).

<sup>2</sup> The *sheen* property is meant to simulate cloth, and so is similar to the **Velvet** shader. The **Velvet** shader has more options though (and I assume slightly different equations), so I wouldn't consider it an exact duplicate.

Comment: Fresnel is also integrated into the shader, also the OP asked which shaders were obsolete not still required.

Comment: @NickBosse It was my intention to make clear that none of them were obsolete.

Comment: @NickBosse Fresnel is usually implied when discussing PBR.

Comment: Aha thank you very much :) It is clear now

Comment: Isn't the sheen parameter a replacement for the Velvet shader?

Comment: @R.Navega I added a note about that, thanks.

Comment: "Replacement" is not the right word, I should've used "alternative".
Like you said, a Principled shader with 100% sheen looks different than a Velvet shader, that alone justifies choosing one over the other (the final result).