# What model does blender use for subsurface scattering material in cycles?

Tags: materials, lighting, color, shader-nodes, subsurface-scattering

I was trying to implement subsurface scattering that blender uses in opengl. So I wanted to know what method it uses for subsurface scattering. Is it possible to replicate the effect without ray tracing?

Comment: Related: [Reconstructing the Principled Shader SSS with standard nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/106253/78972)

Comment: @JachymMichal "Cycles supports Christensen-Burley, Random Walk, Cubic, and Gaussian algorithms." (in the link). I don't get what it means. What kind of algorithms are these?

Comment: Hi :). I'm not a developer, but Cycles is open-source so you can look through the code ;)

Comment: @JachymMichal Yeah, I'm currently doing that only. Thanks : )

Answer (score 1):

This is from the Blender [docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/sss.html) about the SSS node.

It should be noted the Random Walk method is only available in Cycles, not Eevee.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I have seen this. But if I want to implement it in opengl so I need the exact procedure on how these are implemented in blender.

Comment: Blender is an open source project so literally anyone can find the source code readily available. This looks like a decent spot to start.
https://github.com/blender/cycles/blob/master/src/scene/shader_nodes.h

Comment: @AayushKumar What exactly do you expect from an answer here? Do you want someone to just paste the source code, or are you expecting a lengthy explanation of what those algorithms do and how they work? Neither are something you could reasonably expect anyone to do nor are they adequate for this site.

Comment: This is a Q&A site, not a forum for open ended discussions. Questions here are expected to be clear and concise and strictly about using Blender. I invite you to [read the help center](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help) to better understand how this site works